# TclError: no display name

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a snippet for Trigno Fun, but I can't figure out why IDLE tells me there is still an error in my code.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import math
 
## constant for slope
## and fixed 3 points
 
ee = 0.04
x1=y1=y2=0
x2=10
x3=5
y3=5*math.sqrt(3)
 
PrevX = 0
PrevY = 150
 
## Scales the Line
 
def scale(x,y,xx,yy):
    x=x*20+100
    y=y*20+100
    xx=xx*20+100
    yy=yy*20+100
    return(x,y,xx,yy)
 
root = Tk()
root.title("Trigno fun 1")
canvas = Canvas(width=400,height=300,bg='white')
canvas.create_line(scale(x1,y1,x2,y2),fill='red')
canvas.create_line(scale(x2,y2,x3,y3),fill='red')
canvas.create_line(scale(x3,y3,x1,y1),fill='red')
 
## positions shifted/swapped till 100th point
## using 3 fixed points
 
for i in range(0,100):
    x4 = ee*x2 + (1-ee)*x3
    y4 = ee*y2 + (1-ee)*y3
    canvas.create_line(scale(x4,y4,x1,y1),fill='red')
    x3=x2
    y3=y2
    x2=x1
    y2=y1
    x1=x4
    y1=y4
     
canvas.pack()
mainloop()
```

And this is the output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TclError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-533e2c3f76bc> in <module>()
----> 1 roots = Tk()
      2 root.title("Trigno Fun")
      3 canvas = Canvas(width=400, height=300, bg='white')
      4 canvas.create_line(scale(x1,y1,x2,y2), fill='red')
      5 canvas.create_line(scale(x2,y2,x3,y3), fill='red')

/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py in __init__(self, screenName, baseName, className, useTk, sync, use)
   2021                 baseName = baseName + ext
   2022         interactive = 0
-> 2023         self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
   2024         if useTk:
   2025             self._loadtk()

TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

As per my understanding, my code is ok but it shows error, don't know why?
Can anyone please guide me, what is the problem in my code?

Comment: Maybe because your IDE doesnt support the use of a window, copy the code over to some other IDE, maybe the python IDLE

Comment: I just tried copying your code, and it works fine in PyCharm

Comment: You are using ipython/Jupyter, not Python IDLE.  As the error said, your environment is either *not having a graphical desktop* or *not setting the DISPLAY environment variable*.

Comment: In colab and when I execute the script with pyinstaller, it show TclError. In Jupyter Notebook and other IDE script runs correctly.